# How to transform a string parenthesis to a parent-child represantion

Tags: perl, data-visualization, parentheses

I'm trying to visualize a formula which is in a single string of this format:

```
AND(operator1(operator2(x,a),operator3(y,b)),operator4(t))
```

There's no limit to how many arguments are in an operator.

Currently I'm trying to solve it in perl. I guess the easiest way is to transform it to a parent-child representation, and then it would be easy to present it in a collapsable way like this:

```
[-]AND(
  [-]operator1(
    [-]operator2(
      x
      a
    )
    [+]operator3(...)
  )
  [-]operator4(
    t
  )
)
```

I doubt i'm the first one to tackle this, but I can't find any such example online. Thanks!

Comment: Define "visualize." Do you want to print out a tree of operators and operands? Or something else?

Comment: Please edit the problem to increase the understandiblity of the Question with an sample o/p

Comment: The question is unclear, but most likely you need to create grammar parser. You can do it using recursive regex matching. Please also take a look into [Regexp::Grammars](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Grammars-1.033/lib/Regexp/Grammars.pm)

Comment: I edit a bit and added an example. But I mostly wish to translate this to a hash and later decide how to show it on a page later

Comment: So you are looking to render this string in some sort of interactive view? If so, that that changes the scope of your question a bit.

Comment: @RickSarvas, I found a way to render it using http://d3js.org/
Now I wish to output the example as:
`
{
 "name": "AND",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "operator1",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "operator2",
     "children": [
      {"name": "x", "size": 1},
      {"name": "a", "size": 1},
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator3",
     "children": [
      {"name": "y", "size": 1},
      {"name": "b", "size": 1},
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "operator4",
   "children": [
    {"name": "t", "size": 1}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
` . Thanks!

Comment: That will require 2 pass processing because you can't tell if you are about to insert a value or another keyword into the JSON string until you have processed the whole string. For that you would need one pass to parse the string into a nested Hash with Arrays and then a second one to render the resulting structure into JSON. BTW - your JSON example has 2 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this a few months ago and think this might be along the lines of what you are looking for...

```
c:\Perl>perl StackOverflow.pl
SomeValue
AND
-operator1
--operator2
---x
---a
--operator3
---y
---b
-operator4
--t

c:\Perl>
```

If so, here's the code (below). It's a bit of a mess, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe

my $SourceString="SomeValue AND (operator1(operator2(x,a),operator3(y,b)),operator4(t))";
my $NodeIndex=0;
my $IndexString="-";
print ProcessString($SourceString, $NodeIndex);
exit;

#----- subs go here -----
sub ProcessString {
    my $TargetString=shift||return undef;
    my $NodeIndex=shift;
    my $ReturnString="";

    #are we starting with a paren or comma?
    if($TargetString=~m/^([\(\)\, ])/) {
        #yep, delete the char and pass it through again for further processing
        if($1 eq " ") {$ReturnString.=ProcessString(substr($TargetString, index($TargetString, $1)+1), $NodeIndex);}
        elsif($1 eq ",") {$ReturnString.=ProcessString(substr($TargetString, index($TargetString, $1)+1), $NodeIndex);}
        elsif($1 eq "(") {$ReturnString.=ProcessString(substr($TargetString, index($TargetString, $1)+1), ++$NodeIndex);}
        elsif($1 eq ")") {$ReturnString.=ProcessString(substr($TargetString, index($TargetString, $1)+1), --$NodeIndex);}
    } else {
        #nope, must be a keyword or the end
        if($TargetString=~m/([\(\)\, ])/) {
            my $KeywordString=substr($TargetString, 0, index($TargetString, $1));
            $ReturnString.=$IndexString x $NodeIndex;
            $ReturnString.=$KeywordString."\n";
            $ReturnString.=ProcessString(substr($TargetString, index($TargetString, $1)), $NodeIndex);
        } else {
            #we should never be here
        } #end keyword check if
    } #end if

    #send the string back
    return $ReturnString;
} #end sub

__END__
```